# refresh parent window after closing thickbox window

Tags: jquery, html, forms, thickbox

I am using Thickbox 3.1 for a login form, using the iframe version.

I want to close the iframe (child) window, then refresh the parent window.

This closes the iframe window, but I need to somehow set it to refresh the parent window

```
<a href="#" onclick="self.parent.tb_remove();">Close</a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="self.parent.tb_remove(); window.location.reload()">Close</a>
```

**Edit:** Maybe that should be:

```
self.parent.location.reload()
```

?

Comment: it closed the thickbox window, but did not refresh the parent page.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<a href="#" onClick="parent.location.reload(1)">Close</a>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
self.parent.location = "page_to_reload";
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that whatever your page is doing isn't instantaneous. For my site I set new values in a table (MySQL) and I had to add a timeout.

I had to do:
setTimeout(function(){parent.location.reload(1)},1000)

Also used this modification to the .js file:
http://designerfoo.com/jquery-thickbox-hack-to-refresh-parent-window-on-tb_close-event.html